# R Package Deepnet: Why sae_dnn_train does not work with large data sets

Tags: r, deep-learning

I am trying [`sae.dnn.train()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deepnet/deepnet.pdf) with 5000 cases, 55-inputs and 3 hidden layers.

Why function nn.predict returns NaN? (vector)

I am using the following command

```
Nrow <-5000
Ncol <- 55
v <- c(rnorm(Nrow*Ncol,1, 0.5))
x <- matrix(v, nrow=Nrow, ncol=Ncol)
y <- c(rep(1, Nrow/2), rep(0, Nrow/2))
dnn <- sae.dnn.train(x, y, hidden = c(100,90,80),activationfun = "tanh", learningrate = 0.6, momentum = 0.5, learningrate_scale = 1.0,output = "sigm", sae_output = "linear", numepochs = 10, batchsize = 100, hidden_dropout = 0, visible_dropout = 0)
yy <- nn.predict(dnn, x)
```